# How do I display on frontend the result of "methods.name.call()" web3 - method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, solidity, web3js

I am developing a document verification system with ReactJS and solidity - smart contract. I want to display the result of my smart contract's `get().call()` method on the frontend, with a popup or even with a simple text.

My question is how can I do this? My `.get().call()` method seems to be working fine without any problem.

Check the image below, that's my code for now. I use `console.log()` to display the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `console.log` function displays your code in the console your codes work well, now you need to change the state by using `this.setState` function or `useState` hook to re-render the component. because in the ReactJS architecture, changing the `state` causes to change the interface. if your component is a class component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

~~~

class YourComponentName extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      result: '',
      ~~~
      ~~~
    };
  }

  onSubmitGet = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    cosnt hash = document.getElementById('hash').value;

    await this.state.contract.methods
      .get(hash)
      .call({ form: this.state.address })
      .then(res => this.setState({ result: res }))
  };

  ~~~

  render() {
    const { result } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.onSubmitGet}>GET</button>
        <div>{result}</div>
      </>
    );
  }
};

The `~~~` means some other codes. actually, with using `setState` the `<div>{result}</div>` will change and show your result.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer it was very useful but i still have some problems. It tells me that result is not only one thing, its array. So i need to create the resul as array. Maybe something like that : 

this.state = {
result: []
}

First of all is that enough? Or i need to specify the "attributes" of the result that returns from smart contract? 
And how do i display it as array? 

thank you very much.

Comment: Dear @ThanasisDes, I know you are new on Stack Overflow. the proper way to ask questions is to post them separately. the first question you asked that I answered is reached now. so mark it as the correct answer with the green tick. and for new questions ask them in the new posts.

Comment: @ThanasisDes, Certainly, ask your question in the new post. but declaring state by `this.state = { result: [] }` is ok and for show in DOM you should use a JavaScript `Array.prototype.map` function. post your new question and then leave its link here and I definitely will come and answer it.

Comment: Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/61282470/11228111 of my new post. I am really sorry for my mistakes.