# "Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, solidity, web3js

I am developing a document verification system with ReactJS and solidity - smart contract. I want to display the result of my smart contract's `get().call()` method on the frontend, with a popup or even with a simple text. The problem I am facing now is that when I am trying to display the response of the method, it throws to me that error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Here is the code of my solidity contract:

```js
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
contract Proof1 {
  struct FileDetails {
    uint256 timestamp;
    string owner;
  }
  mapping(string => FileDetails) files;
  event logFileAddedStatus(
    bool status,
    uint256 timestamp,
    string owner,
    string fileHash
);

function set(string memory owner, string memory fileHash) public {
  if (files[fileHash].timestamp == 0) {
    files[fileHash] = FileDetails(block.timestamp, owner);

    emit logFileAddedStatus(true, block.timestamp, owner, fileHash);
  } else {
    emit logFileAddedStatus(false, block.timestamp, owner, fileHash);
  }
}

function get(string memory fileHash)
public
view
returns (uint256 timestamp, string memory owner)
{
  return (files[fileHash].timestamp, files[fileHash].owner);
}}
```

Here is `.get().call()` method inside onClick method:

```js
onSubmitGet = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const hash = document.getElementById("hash").value;

  this.state.design = await this.state.contract.methods
    .get(hash)
    .call({ from: this.state.address })
    .then((res) => this.setState({ result: res }));
};
```

And this is how I display the result with React:

```js
const { result } = this.state;

<div>{result}</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You should post your code as text rather than screenshots. I think that's why you're getting down-votes.

Comment: Try `console.log(result)` and see what type of object it is. It has to be either a string, `null` or a react component instance. If it isn't then make it one of those, and it should work...

Comment: If i do something like this: `({result: JSON.stringify(res)})` it returns to me the as json the response and display it. The problem here is that i dont want as json i want to find other way to display it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you write the below code:

```js
this.state.design = await this.state.contract.methods
```

The ReactJS doesn't have `two-way-data-binding`, The ReactJS is not like VueJS or Angular, for changing state you should use `this.setState` or `useState`. the `this.state.design =` never change anything of states.

Now for your question. set the initial state for the result like below:

```js
this.state = {
  result: undefined,
};
```

Then in the JSX write it like below:

```js
const { result } = this.state;

<div>
  {result && result.map((item, index) => (
    <div key={item.uniqueThing}>{item.title}</div>
  ))}
</div>
```

Actually, you don't need `index`, I just wanna aware you that you can have it. even you can write it better:

```js
const { result } = this.state;

<div>
  {result && result.map(({ title, uniqueThing }) => (
    <div key={uniqueThing}>{title}</div>
  ))}
</div>
```

*Note:* you definitely should pass the `key` to the first JSX element of the map callback function return, and it should be unique, please do not use `index` it has a bad cost for ReactJS to handle it maybe sometimes fall into bad bugs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i did exactly what you say to me and still is not working. It throws to me that error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): result.map is not a function. Is something that i need to change?

Comment: @ThanasisDes, It means your ajax request does not return an array. the map function is just available under an array.

Comment: @ThanasisDes, see the `res` result in your Network tab if it is possible please put a screenshot of your ajax response in your question post.

Comment: I added the screen shot in the end of my question. You can click it and read it.

Comment: @ThanasisDes, it is obvious that is not an array, it is an Object. the API design is not very well, the backend developer could pass the `0, 1` keys as an array and make it separate from `timestamp`, can you change the API response from backend?